# Constructor from string VS lexical cast from string?

Tags: c++, boost, constructor

I just realized my code base was a bit incoherent with some objects being constructed from  strings using a constructor `A(const std::string&)` and some others being constructed from strings using `boost::lexical_cast<A>(const std::string&)`.

In my understanding, these fulfill the same need but do not behave the same in many ways, exceptions on a badly formatted string and conversions being the first ones that spring to my mind but I'm sure there are also other implications. So my questions is: What should I be using and why?

---

Edit: as per @hetepeperfan's comment, I'm transforming the std::string arguments in const std::string&, which is what I meant in the first place

Comment: I think generally your constructors should also use const std::string unless your constructor is really ment to change the string.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<T>(U)` can convert `U` to `T`, if `U` has output operator and `T` has input operator... But what does your c'tor depends on how it's implemented.

Comment: @hetepeperfan right, I just changed it.

Comment: @ForEveR, certainly, but considering we're converting from a string that has an output operator and we're implementing `T::operator>>`, there are degrees of freedom too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine a class `InputFile` (similar to `std::ifstream`) that takes the string representing the path to the file in the file-system:

```
InputFile f("/dir/file.txt");
use(f);
```

Using `boost::lexical_cast` here would be at least weird.

I guess this observation could be generalized this way: If your type `A` represents a value "compatible" with `std::string` or convertible to `std::string`, you have two options. But if you are exposing in the interface a constructor that takes one non-optional argument of type `std::string` for other purposes than converting a value, only using the constructor makes sense (and this constructor should probably be `explicit`).

Comment: Good point, I was more or less thinking about the serialized fields of a message where you can always go in the two directions.

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, these fulfill the same need [...]

They do not fulfill the same need. The interface used to create objects should always express best the semantics behind creating the object. A lexical cast is a cast (reinterpretation) of the string value to an object instance. If your object is constructed with a string value but not *from* the value in the string, using boost::lexical_cast will just be confusing.

> [...] but do not behave the same in many ways, exceptions on a badly formatted string and conversions being the first ones that spring to my mind but I'm sure there are also other implications. So my questions is: What should I be using and why?

If your object can be constructed from *any* string value (i.e. does not depend on the value in the string but just copies the string internally), then you should pass it directly to the constructor.

If passing a string value to the constructor means you could create an instance with an invalid value, you should either use a factory function (that throws an error *before* instantiating an object) or [less prefered] add exception validation in the constructor (less optimal, less clean and in most cases worse design).

If your object instance models a value/type specialization that can be created from the interpretation of the value in the string (a "cast"), then you should support creating it through `boost::lexical_cast<YourClass>(const std::string&)`.

**Edit:** if you construct an object with a name (some logger object for example) but the functionality/value of the logger doesn't depend on what the name is (the object logs the same, just with a different name), then you should not define a lexical_cast - based implementation (because the name doesn't change the functionality of the logger).

If instead you create an object who'se value/functionality depends on the value in the string (parse the value in the string and transform it into a 'complex number' class instance) then the behavior of the instance depends on what was in the string (`lexical_cast<ComplexNo>("(0 + 0i)")` will return something that cannot be divided by, as opposed to what  `lexical_cast<ComplexNo>("(1 + 0i)")`). In this case (a value object dependent on what's in the string) you *should* support lexical_cast.

Basically, provide lexical_cast-based implementation for value-objects.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your sentence: "If your object is constructed with a string value but not from the value in the string, using boost::lexical_cast will just be confusing.". Can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: ok I get it now. Sort of looks like the same argument that Andrzej's answer.